# Slow internet speeds (but fast speed test results)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, performance, internet

About a month ago I started to notice that uploading to Google Drive was suddenly much slower than it should be. Up until January I was paying for 100Mb up and the same down and could upload to GDrive at around 10MB/s pretty consistently. However, the speeds I'm getting now are less than 1MB and I've tried everything I can think of to fix it, but so for have not had any luck.

- I've spoken with my ISP 3 times now and each time they have told me there is no bandwidth or speed limiting in place. I thought that this was the most likely scenario, but it doesn't seem to be the case.
- I've spoken with Google support and they say that there are no limits in place
- I've tried resetting the router to factory settings
- I've made sure my OS is up to date (macOS Mojave)
- I've tried disabling the firewall, to see if anything there was blocking connections
- I've updated to the latest version of the software I use to upload to GDrive (rclone). I've also made sure that I'm using my own Google API key so as to avoid limiting
- I've upgraded my internet and am now contracted for 600Mb/s. When I run a speed test I don't see 600Mb, but the results aren't exactly slow: [Speed test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnRoI.png). There was no difference in upload speed between going from 100 to 600.
- I've tried uploading to Microsoft's One Drive instead of Google to see if it was specifically connecting to them where there were issues. One Drive did upload slightly faster at around 4MB/s, but even this is much slower than the speed I should be getting
- I've tried a different laptop (Windows 7) and the speeds there were also much slower than I should be getting. I've seen that the Win7 laptop has drivers from 2012, but when I update it says these are the latest.
- I have tried uploading from my phone and the speeds are much quicker (20MB/s roughly). This narrows down the issue to my laptop(s)
- I've used Bit Defender on my macbook and it was unable to find any threats

I ran `traceroute` to `drive.google.com` with the following output:

```
traceroute: Warning: drive.google.com has multiple addresses; using 74.125.136.139
traceroute to drive.google.com (74.125.136.139), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  284.830 ms  3.833 ms  3.845 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * 101.red-81-46-65.customer.static.ccgg.telefonica.net (81.46.65.101)  5.254 ms
 4  * 106.red-81-46-65.customer.static.ccgg.telefonica.net (81.46.65.106)  4.960 ms  11.438 ms
 5  98.red-81-46-8.customer.static.ccgg.telefonica.net (81.46.8.98)  4.951 ms
    94.red-81-46-8.customer.static.ccgg.telefonica.net (81.46.8.94)  8.494 ms  3.992 ms
 6  * * *
 7  72.14.211.154 (72.14.211.154)  7.307 ms  4.517 ms
    72.14.219.20 (72.14.219.20)  5.161 ms
 8  108.170.253.248 (108.170.253.248)  5.837 ms
    108.170.253.231 (108.170.253.231)  5.547 ms
    108.170.253.247 (108.170.253.247)  5.068 ms
 9  172.253.50.177 (172.253.50.177)  21.180 ms
    172.253.50.72 (172.253.50.72)  5.967 ms
    172.253.50.68 (172.253.50.68)  4.850 ms
10  216.239.54.148 (216.239.54.148)  98.047 ms
    216.239.54.150 (216.239.54.150)  98.531 ms
    74.125.242.178 (74.125.242.178)  4.996 ms
11  216.239.41.237 (216.239.41.237)  33.610 ms
    172.253.50.177 (172.253.50.177)  20.999 ms
    216.239.41.237 (216.239.41.237)  33.969 ms
12  216.239.40.130 (216.239.40.130)  112.506 ms
    216.239.40.132 (216.239.40.132)  311.858 ms
    216.239.54.150 (216.239.54.150)  98.180 ms
13  216.239.48.31 (216.239.48.31)  106.193 ms  105.194 ms
    216.239.48.6 (216.239.48.6)  246.752 ms
14  216.239.40.130 (216.239.40.130)  111.852 ms *  112.809 ms
15  * 216.239.50.99 (216.239.50.99)  111.710 ms *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  74.125.136.139 (74.125.136.139)  113.103 ms  110.832 ms *
```

Just wondering if anybody has any other ideas for what I could try. My ISP seems pretty certain that the problem is on my end, not theirs, but as far as I know I haven't changed any settings from when it was working well in January until now. I've ran out of ideas and don't really know what else I can try. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How are you connecting to the router? What other devices use said router (have you checked that no one is connected without your knowledge? have you checked your machine for spyware?

Comment: I'm connected via WiFi, and I haven't checked if anyone else is connected or for spyware, no.

Comment: Does the speed differs while connecting to a router via cooper? try to test it...

Comment: Anycase - when you upload to GD, the traffic follows as (PC)-air-(router)-(ISP router)-(ISP router)-...-(somebody's router)-...-(Google router)-(Google router)-(Google drive). And each router may shape your traffic (in general or dependent by its type/proto/etc.), including intermediate nodes which are not controlled by any org you have spoken with. Again - tomorrow the route from you to GD may change, and the problem will die...

Comment: Are you uploading from the same drive? How are speeds across the network? Please be sure to update your question with the new information and not just add it as a comment.

Comment: Even if it's at a much slower speed than you should have, yet likely faster than you are getting, use the laptop connected to some other network (work, local wifi hotspot, etc.) and see if the speed test and/or Google results are still unexpectedly low.

Comment: What type of connection are you using to connect to the ISP? Coaxial cable network, fiber optic network, etc.

Comment: @TomDippé - I'd do a spyware check (I hope tools exist for Mac...), and try connecting via a cable rather than wired.

Comment: Akina is that really a possibility? That it's just due to bad luck why I've been having speeds much slower than they should be for the past month?
shawn I only ever really do uploading to GDrive. However, watching Netflix I do not have any issues.
I'm not currently able to run any tests with a different network or using a cable instead of WiFi. I will have to run these tests later and update here. The connection to my ISP is via fiber optic.

Comment: @TomDippé Yes, many ISPs have several uplinks to the Internet in general, so it could be that they temporarily switched from the "regular" uplink to a backup. Additionally, many have direct peerings with large sites such as Google or Amazon at IXPs; it could be that they had a peering with Google, but temporarily switched it off so now data goes through a transit ISP. (Importantly, note that routing is not bidirectional – data you send to a site can take a completely different path than data you receive from the same site!) Of course, the ISP might just have actual problems internally, too.

Comment: I have ran a full system scan using Bit Defender on my Mac laptop and it has reported no threats detected.

Comment: I've updated the post with new information

Answer (score 0):

Could it be how your ISP is routing the traffic? Perhaps there have been some changes in how they route the traffic.

We once had this problem. Very slow speed from our office in England to our server in Denmark. A trace route showed a crazy route.
We changed ISP. The new ISP used a different route to Denmark and the speed was fine.

Maybe you can do a test with a mobile broadband connection from your phone. Just to make sure it is the internet connection and not your computer that is the cause.

Comment: I have just tested it from my phone using the WiFi and the speeds are more acceptable. I hadn't thought of doing that before so thanks for helping me narrow it down. I guess this is an issue with my laptop

Comment: I've added a traceroute output to the op